# Are empty for loops even executed in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I was wondering if the condition inside for loop is always executed if it's a mathematical operation like:

```
int margin = 100;

for(int i=0; i<margin/2;i++);//is margin divided by two at every cycle?
```

so I have written the following program:

```
long margin = 1000000000, halfOfMargin = margin/2;
clock_t begin_time;
clock_t stop_time;

for(long j=0;j<10;++j)
{
    begin_time = clock();
    for(long i=0;i<margin/2;i++);
    stop_time = clock ();

    cout <<"With margin/2 :"<< float( stop_time - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"\n";
}
for(long j=0;j<10;++j)
{
    begin_time = clock();
    for(long i=0;i<halfOfMargin;i++);
    stop_time = clock ();
    cout <<"With halfOfMargin :"<< float( stop_time - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"\n";
}
```

to test the two methods separately, (sorry for the messy code).

I have concluded that in Debug configuration the divide version is even faster than the second aproach. What surprised me was that when I switched to Release, I got the output of 0 for each of the versions every time, which would have been imposible if the `for` instructions were actually executed (in Debug configuration the time of each output was about a second and a half).

My question is that if it is possible to be skiped instructions by the compiler if it finds them unnecesary, and if not why the times were so different for those two cases?

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2012 express as an IDE with the default compiler.

Comment: The optimizer  is usually very good at skipping things.

Comment: Why not just step through it using f10  and breakpoints to find out what it does or doesn't do?

Comment: Not only is it possible it is common thing you have to work around when trying to time things trivially.  If you really wan to know check the assembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard describes the behavior of an abstract machine.

Certain parts of its behavior are externally observable.

Any behavior whose effects are not observable can be skipped under what is known as the "as-if" rule.

That means the compiler is free to skip useless code.  In some situations, it can even skip an infinite loop by proving that it changes nothing anyone could spot, set the state to be what would permit the loop to exit, and exit the loop.

In "debug", compilers tend to optimize far less.

Answer (score 3):

As the 'margin' variable is local and not modified, the compiler can see that it never changes and will only do the test once.

If you call a function and are testing the result then it probably can't.

Try adding volatile to the variable definition and running it again. Then the compiler will think that the variable could be modified from another thread and perform the test every loop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the compiler do this. This falls under the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) - the code may be reorganized as long as the observable behaviour doesn't change. Since the change to `i` in your loop cannot be observed by anything (i.e. a function the compiler can't see the body of or a IO function), it can be sped up.

If you look at the code generated by clang or gcc, it'll also be optimized out:

```
void foo(int n)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < n/2; ++i);
  sink(i);
}
```

[clang](https://godbolt.org/g/uO2KxF):

```
foo(int):                                # @foo(int)
# BB#0:
        #DEBUG_VALUE: foo:n <- %EDI
        #DEBUG_VALUE: foo:i <- 0
        mov     eax, edi
        shr     eax, 31
        add     eax, edi
        xor     ecx, ecx
        sar     eax
        cmovs   eax, ecx
        mov     edi, eax
        jmp     sink(int)                # TAILCALL
```

[gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/JPy2sr):

```
foo(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        shr     eax, 31
        add     eax, edi
        xor     edi, edi
        sar     eax
        test    eax, eax
        jle     .L2
.L3:
        add     edi, 1
        cmp     edi, eax
        jne     .L3
.L2:
        jmp     sink(int)
```